# Ask about disk space

Tags: disk, kvm-virtualization

Now I install Ubuntu 16.04 and install `kvm` on this machine.

My problem is when I create a virtual machine (see the first screenshot below) which is called `generic.qcow2` with 21GB of space, when I type command `du` to see disk usage, I found space is less than this storage, so is there any solution to make size when I type `du` like size which I decide for virtual machine?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `du` show you how many space are used (by files, folder ...), so there is only 3.4 (Mb or MB, don't know) that are used, but still have 21GB reserved for your virtual machine

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). @damadam Thank you for your edit suggestion. Please note that `1rst` is wrong, write either first or 1st. (I’ve met the same mistake in some of your previous edits already.)

Comment: Have you been satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657)

Answer (score 3):

The [`*.qcow2` files are created as sparse files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435501/54675), so the unused space is not occupied.

You can use the `--apparent-size` option of the [`du`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) command to reveal the designed size of sparse files.

If you want to convert the file to a fixed size, you can [use the `cp` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435499/qcow2-actual-size/435501#435501), then move the file into the original place. NOTE: Use this command when the file is not in use.

```
cp generic.qcow2 generic.qcow2.tmp && mv generic.qcow2.tmp generic.qcow2
```

### See also

- [Sparse file on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sparse_file)